# Trouble transferring items from ListOf

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

I'm making a program that allows users to add tables to a list.
But I'm having trouble getting the list to show on listBox

The table and its properties get added to the original list in the class just fine, but once I try to display it, the data seems to be gone.
I'm assuming i'm doing something wrong with my lists but I can't figure out what.
I tried putting the list in another array list now, but no result.

```
Imports Table_Tracker_Library
Public Class Main_Form
    Private Property _Table As New Table
    Private Property _ShowList As Table()

Private Sub Btn_Add_Table_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Add_Table.Click
    Form_Create_Button.Show()
End Sub



Public Sub Renew()
    _ShowList = _Table.GetList()
    Me.LB_ActiveTables.ClearSelected()
    For Each table As Table In _ShowList
        LB_ActiveTables.Items.Add("Table #" & table.Number)
    Next
    LB_ActiveTables.Refresh()
End Sub

'Private Function GetList() As Table()
'    Dim TempList As New List(Of Table)
'    For Each table As Table In _Table.ListOfTable
'        TempList.Add(table)
'    Next
'    Return TempList.ToArray
'End Function
End Class
```

-

```
Imports Table_Tracker_Library
Public Class Form_Create_Button
    Private Property _Table As New Table

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_addtable.Click
        _Table.CreateTable(Me.txb_TableNr.Text, Me.txb_PplNr.Text)
        Main_Form.Renew()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_discard.Click
        Me.Close()
        End Sub
End Class
```

-

```
Public Class Table
    Public Property Number As Int32
    Public Property NumberOfPeople As Int32
    Public Property ListOfTable As New List(Of Table)



    Public Sub CreateTable(TableNrString As String, PersonNrString As String)
        Dim TableNR As Int32 = CInt(TableNrString)
        Dim PersonNr As Int32 = CInt(PersonNrString)
        Dim NewTable As New Table With {.Number = TableNR, .NumberOfPeople = PersonNr}
        AddTable(NewTable)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddTable(Table As Table)
        ListOfTable.Add(Table)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetList() As Table()
        Dim TempList As New List(Of Table)
        For Each table As Table In ListOfTable
            TempList.Add(table)
        Next
        Return TempList.ToArray
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Do you mean that `LB_ActiveTables` is not populated with the `"Table #" & table.Number` values? It should work fine.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean, the values are not displayed, but when i debug with step in, it looks like it never adds the items to the ListBox.

Comment: It works fine with me (and the code seems fine too). What you mean with "never adds", it does not enter in the loop? If this is the case, `_ShowList` wouldn't have any item. If it enters in the loop and you can access `LB_ActiveTables`, the items should be added without any problem.

Comment: The Items never get placed in TempList, and if i try without the GetList sub they will never go to where i want to go, but the original list does hold the items. I'm working with 2 projects that are linked together, one for class library and one for the forms, could this cause any issues?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the "re-declaration" of `_Table` (main and secondary form). When using the secondary form, you rely on the local variable for `CreateTable` but then you call `Main_Form.Renew()` which uses the other `_Table` (the one declared in the main form, which is empty). Use just one `_Table` in the main form or change `Renew()` such that it takes the given `_Table` as an argument. In any case, this has nothing to do with the `ListBox`, please, update the title of this question.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, thank you. One last question, ... already found my answer to it. thx anyway :)

Comment: (You are welcome). Yes, `.Clear()` :) Or you might re-initialise the list every time by writing  `ListOfTable = New List(Of Table)` at the start of `CreateTable()`.

Comment: Do not write "Solved" in the title. And we know you want help. That's why you asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the `private` to `public` in the primary form

```
Public Class Main_Form
    Public Property Table As New Table
    Private Property _ShowList As Table()

.....
```

And used the main form's table property on the secondary form

```
Public Class Form_Create_Button


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_addtable.Click
        If IsNumeric(txb_TableNr.Text) = True AndAlso IsNumeric(txb_PplNr.Text) Then
            If Main_Form.Table.TableIsAvailable(txb_TableNr.Text, txb_PplNr.Text) = True Then
                Main_Form.Table.CreateTable(Me.txb_TableNr.Text, Me.txb_PplNr.Text)
                Main_Form.RenewListBox()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Table already taken!", "Invalid Table", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid table number or amount of people", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_discard.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub



End Class
```